# How to start project with TabWidget without QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtabwidget

Everytime you create new project from Qt Creator there is on top QWidget which you can delete.

[image]

You can of course write the code manually as this:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

where Main class is inherited from QTabWidget and everything works.

```
class Main(QTabWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

**Is there any way how to achieve this from Qt Designer?
How can i delete QWidget and put QTabWidget on top of hierarchy?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a GUI with Qt Designer you can choose the widget that you take as base as shown in the following image:

[image]

Generally we choose from the first option `templates/forms`, but we can also choose from `Widgets` (Second option)

[image]

In this second option we can choose as a basis for `QTabWidget`.

[image]

Comment: Ahh i am so blind. I have never think that "Widgets" option can be scroll out and i always use options from templates. In my version of Qt Designer it is not so visible as it in your version.

Comment: Open Qt Designer directly, do not use it through Qt Creator.